# What is $\lim_{ n \to \infty }(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+2n}\rfloor)$?

Tags: limits

If $a_n=\sqrt{n^2+2n}$ and $f(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function, then what is the limit
$$\lim_{ n \to \infty }f(a_n) \ \ ?$$

I tried:

$\lim_{ n \to \infty }a_n=\lim_{ n \to \infty }\sqrt{n^2+2n}=\infty$

$\lim_{ n \to \infty }f(\infty)=?$

Comment: Please define $[x]$. Do you mean the integer part, a.k.a. the "floor function", $\lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: @FlybyNight [x]="floor function

Comment: Note that because of the floor function, $f(x)$ doesn't care how _large_ $x$ is, only how far away it is from being an integer. Therefore, it's not relevant at all that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \infty$. You should rather turn your focus on this: How far is $\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}$ from being an integer, for very large $n$?

Comment: @Arthur You should make this into an answer.

Comment: The limit of this function is within 0 to 1.

Comment: @Arthur it depends on the n,so this function doesn't have limits. What I mean is theat the limit is indeterminate

Comment: @Namasivayam Kalithasan How do you know that the function doesn't have a limit?

Comment: @Arthur Come on. Stop being a tease and post your answer!

Comment: @FlybyNight there is already an answer which quantifies that difference (and is almost correct in doing so).

Comment: Also, am I the only one bothered by the fact that writing $$\lim_{ n \to \infty }a_n=\sqrt{n^2+2n}=\infty$$
is barely a valid notation?

Comment: @FlybyNight Your answer is more than good enough, if only you correct the minor flaw and undelete it.

Comment: Quite easy...its obvious that x and floor (x) is different at most by 1@fernando

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan So, you conclude "quite eas[il]y" that the limit does not exist, while it *does* exist?

Comment: @Clement c , I'm a mathematician ,I won't conclude just by seeing that fact but it too play a very crucial role in that limit

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan I guess I was not clear. (1) You claim that it is easy to see that the limit does not exist. Yet, (2) the limit does exist (it is equal to $1$), as one of the answers shows, and one can see for instance by an asymptotic development of $a_n$. Hence my comment, to point out that (1) and (2) are, let's say, hard to reconcile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $n \leq \sqrt{n^2} < \sqrt{n^2+2n} <\sqrt{(n+1)^2} =n+1$, so $\lfloor a_n \rfloor = n$.

Then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n^2+2n} - n =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+2n} - n)(\sqrt{n^2+2n} + n)}{\sqrt{n^2+2n} + n} $$ $$=
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n} + n} = 1.$$

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @ClementC. The question asks for the limit and this gives it?

Comment: Oops. Mea culpa.

Comment: @Sil Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: Did you mean the both N are equal?

Comment: -1 You mean floor $(a_n)$ is n,and this n is integer but in the limit the n is any real number.you're wrong

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan  If two things are not equal, I don't use the same variable for it.  And, no, $n$ is the index of a sequence, so it's not "any reall number".  It's a positive integer

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan Your comment seems misguided. We are asked for the limit of $f(a_n)$, when $n\to\infty$ (so implicitly $n$ is an integer, as it is the index of the sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sqrt{n^2+2n } = \sqrt{(n+1)^2-1} \approx n+1 - \frac 12 \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: While the conclusion wouldn't change, your development is wrong. There is no square in the denominator: $$\sqrt{n^2+2n} = n+1-\frac{1}{2n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: So $\lim_{ n \to \infty }a_n=\sqrt{n^2+2n}=1?$

Comment: No. The limit you are asking **in your question** is $1$, the one in your comment is of course $\infty$. (Or, actually, the way written just above, does not even "parse")

Comment: @ClementC. thanks for the catch!